# can't change active_admin column width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using the github version of active_Admin as can be seen from my gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

I am trying to change the column width of a column in an index table.  According to the documentation found [here](http://activeadmin.info/docs/12-arbre-components.html#columns), it should be done like this:

```
column :notes, min_width: "400px"
column :notes, max_width: "800px"
```

However, the code above is not working.  The column is 100px.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4091

> Unfortunately max_width only exists on "pages" (i.e. register_page),
>   and not on "resources" (i.e. register). Instead you can do this:
>
> `.col-<column_name> {   max-width: 200px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
columns do
  column max_width: "800px", min_width: "400px" do
    span "notes contents goes here"
  end
end
```

See **Custom Column Widths** section from the [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/12-arbre-components.html#columns).

#### Update (tested and working!)

If the above way does not work for you, you can still do it the following way:

```
column :notes do
   div(class: "notes") do 
     span "notes contents goes here"
   end  
end
```

Define the css rule in `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` file:

```
div.notes { width: 500px; }
```

Comment: That's not the column name.  I tried that.  it's actually column content.  Whatever you put inside the span tag fills the columns.

Comment: it gives me this: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Comment: I think it will work without the column name: `notes`.
Try this: `columns do
  column max_width: "800px", min_width: "400px" do
    span "notes contents goes here"
  end
end`

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work.  i get the same error.

Comment: This is very weird. I am not sure if that's a bug in active admin itself. I have to check their source code.

Comment: I have this in my code: `column(:name, sortable: :name)                       { |p| link_for_plan(p, :name) }` which works. So, when I pass the column name to the column method with sortable param it works. And their documentation shows that `max_width ` and `min_width` can be passed as params to the column method. So, why it is not working? I don't know. Need to dig their source code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This works today

```
index do
  style do
    [".col-name{width: 130px}"].join(' ')
  end
  column :name
  actions
end
```

Active admin uses this gem. 
https://activeadmin.github.io/arbre/

Above puts the style right into the HTML. That's okay because it works.

I mean your HTML will be ugly, but it works.